# PHP and javascript onclick 2 functions

Tags: javascript, php

Hello i need your help.
 i have this button function:

```js
onclick="javascript:addProduct(\'prm\',' . $item['pk_i_id'] . ');"
```

It is working fine but i need to add another onclick function , i need it  to open a new window too when clicked all at once. 
 The new window i need to open is:

```html
onclick="window.open('https://chile.dineromail.com/Carrito/cart.asp?NombreItem=Pagar Premium&TipoMoneda=1&PrecioItem=2490.00&NroItem=-&DireccionExito=http://www.comprafy.cl/paymentpro/checkout&DireccionFracaso=http://www.comprafy.cl/paymentpro/menu&DireccionEnvio=0&Mensaje=0&MediosPago=4,5,6,21,23,2,7&Comercio=1313434','Carrito','width=750,height=475,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,directories=no');"
```

i already tried :

```html
onclick="javascript:addProduct(\'prm\',' . $item['pk_i_id'] . ');window.open("https://chile.dineromail.com/Carrito/cart.asp?NombreItem=Pagar Premium&TipoMoneda=1&PrecioItem=2490.00&NroItem=-&DireccionExito=http://www.comprafy.cl/paymentpro/checkout&DireccionFracaso=http://www.comprafy.cl/paymentpro/menu&DireccionEnvio=0&Mensaje=0&MediosPago=4,5,6,21,23,2,7&Comercio=1313434','Carrito','width=750,height=475,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,directories=no");"
```

But i get this error: 
syntax error, unexpected ','  which is the comma before and after 'Carrito'
Is there a posibility to do this?. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, please edit your question to include what you have tried and what didn't work, please also remember to include the errors you get.

Comment: Already did it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted ?

```
onclick="javascript:addProduct('prm','" . $item['pk_i_id'] . "');window.open('https://chile.dineromail.com/Carrito/cart.asp?NombreItem=Pagar Premium&TipoMoneda=1&PrecioItem=2490.00&NroItem=-&DireccionExito=http://www.comprafy.cl/paymentpro/checkout&DireccionFracaso=http://www.comprafy.cl/paymentpro/menu&DireccionEnvio=0&Mensaje=0&MediosPago=4,5,6,21,23,2,7&Comercio=1313434','Carrito','width=750,height=475,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,directories=no');"
```

Just replace your `onClick` attribute with the above code.

Comment: Yes kind of , i edited some details, if you could help me i will really appreciate it.!

Comment: @JorgeMerinoSantander I have edited my answer. Once check.

Comment: not working i have a comma breaking it. Do you know where i can get some developer to fix this? i can pay for this work..

Comment: I tried it. It worked for me. What does this mean ? `I have a comma breaking it`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
onclick="javascript:addProduct(\'prm\',' . $item['pk_i_id'] . '); window.open("http://www.google.com");"
```

Hope It helps!